# Unit testing localized strings

Tags: c#, .net, localization

We have a couple thousand localized strings in our application.  I am wanting to create a unit test to iterate through all the keys and all of our supported languages to make sure that every language has every key present in the default (English) resx file.

My idea is to use Reflection to get all the keys from the `Strings` class, then use a `ResourceManager` to compare the retrieved value for every key in every language and compare it to make sure it doesn't match the English version, but of course, some words are the same across multiple languages.

Is there a way to check if the `ResourceManager` obtained its value from a satellite assembly vs. the default resource file?

Example call:

```
string en = resourceManager.GetString("MyString", new CultureInfo("en"));
string es = resourceManager.GetString("MyString", new CultureInfo("es"));

//compare here
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Call the `ResourceManager.GetResourceSet` method to get all the resources for the neutral and localized cultures, and then compare the two collections:

```
ResourceManager resourceManager = new ResourceManager(typeof(Strings));
IEnumerable<string> neutralResourceNames = resourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, true, false)
    .Cast<DictionaryEntry>().Select(entry => (string)entry.Key);
IEnumerable<string> localizedResourceNames = resourceManager.GetResourceSet(new CultureInfo("es"), true, false)
    .Cast<DictionaryEntry>().Select(entry => (string)entry.Key);

Console.WriteLine("Missing localized resources:");
foreach (string name in neutralResourceNames.Except(localizedResourceNames))
{
    Console.WriteLine(name);
}

Console.WriteLine("Extra localized resources:");
foreach (string name in localizedResourceNames.Except(neutralResourceNames))
{
    Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```

Comment: This is perfect, Michael!  Thank you!